# Hexadecimal string manipulation to extract counters?

Tags: python, string, data-manipulation

I have the following four hexadecimal strings:

```
0xb5695e9bfeef8ed587f107c6babe281
0xaa57de98aeefafeb66b81993843f6f0
0xf6a96839eeefd484d61f932fe14d56f
0x1b623f449ef026595bd0d9197c33d84
```

What I want is to locate and extract counters in those strings such as:

```
0xb5695e9bf[eef8]ed587f107c6babe281 --> 0xeef8 = 61176
0xaa57de98a[eefa]feb66b81993843f6f0 --> 0xeefa = 61178
0xf6a96839e[eefd]484d61f932fe14d56f --> 0xeefd = 61181
0x1b623f449[ef02]6595bd0d9197c33d84 --> 0xef02 = 61186
```

I precise that, originally, I do not know the format of the string. Except the fact that it is an hexadecimal string, it means that, for different sets of strings, the counter can change location.
Also, I precise that I do not know the length of the counter (in this case it is 2-byte long but it may be 3, 4, 5 or even 1 byte-long).

To resume my problem: how can I manipulate hexadecimal strings with Python to 1) understand that they contain counters and 2) extract their values?

Comment: For point 1 understand they contain counters. Is there any logic for determining if a particular set of bytes represent a counter? If not I don't see how you can know. Is a counter just an int value?

Comment: How do you define what is "counter"?

Comment: What pattern do "counters" have? What differentiates it from the other hexadecimal digits? You need to know this information to do what you wish.

Comment: Are the non-counter digits random, and if so what would prevent them from forming something that just looked like a pattern?

Comment: When responding to a comment, you should place an @other_users_name in it so that person will get notified you have done so. Regardless, I suggest you [edit] your question and add that explanation to it. However, I don't think it's definitive because, for example, there are more digits in each string beyond `[eef8]` that also fit the pattern you mention.

Comment: @PaulRooney : A counter is a sequence of bytes at a same location for a given set of strings and that is always incremented. Thus, for a different set of strings, the counter can change its location. Indeed, behind the hexadecimal representation, a counter is "just" an int value.

Comment: @AndrejKesely : A counter is defined as a structure (a sequence of bytes at the same location for a given set of strings) that is always incremented. There may be several counters in a string but finding only one is enough.

Comment: @sc4re I don't see how you can recognise a 'counter' in some binary data. It doesn't look any different to the rest of the data or if its not in a specific known place. The provider of the data has to give you some scheme to interpret it. If they don't, you are stuck with just a load of bytes.

Comment: @martineau: A counter is a sequence of bytes at the same location for a given set of strings that is always incremented. Most of the time, the non-counter digits are random and do not follow any pattern. The fact is that several counters can be included in a string but finding only one is enough. What I want to do is to make my computer understand that a particular set of strings is linked thanks to a counter.

Comment: sc4re: By those rules the "pattern" shown in your question could have also been 3, 4, or even the whole length of the remaining bytes in the strings. In other words, they're not sufficient to be able to detect the patterns and be able ignore non-pattern data. You need a more constraining definition. You also don't seem to have tried anything yourself.